Line from proof of Proposition 2.2 from Liu's Algebraic geometry
I am unable to understand this line from the proof of Prop 2.2 from Liu's book. 
I don't see why it is clear that $\mathcal{O}_X(U_{ijk})$ is finitely generated over $\mathcal{O}_X(V_{ik})$. Also, I am wondering if it is supposed to be written $\mathcal{O}_Y(V_{ik})$ instead of $\mathcal{O}_X(V_{ik})$. Liu notes that $V_{ik}$ is principal in $V_{i}$, and this implies that $U_{ijk}$ is principal in $U_{ij}$ since the preimage of a principal open under a morphism of affine schemes is again principal ($f_{|U_{ij}}: U_{ij} \to V_i$ in this case; We take the preimage of $V_{ik}$ which is principal in $V_i$) . However I don't see how that helps here. I am grateful for all guidance (I have been stuck on this for 3 days and am finally reaching out for help)

$V_{ik}\subset V$ is a principal affine open subset, i.e. $V_{ik}=D(\varphi)\subset V$ for some $\varphi\in\mathcal{O}_V(V)$. From the definition, $U_{\alpha}=U_{ijk}=U_{ij}\cap f^{-1}(V_{ik})$, which is exactly $D(f^\sharp(\varphi))\subset U_{ij}$, where $f^\sharp:\mathcal{O}_V(V)\to\mathcal{O}_X(U_{ij})$ is the map induced by $f$. So the claim boils down to "if $\psi:A\to B$ is a ring map giving $B$ the structure of a finitely-generated $A$-algebra, then the localization $\psi_a:A_a\to B_a$ for any element $a\in A$ also gives $B_a$ the structure of a finitely-generated $A_a$-algebra".
But this is direct: we just take the same generators. That is, if $b_1,\cdots,b_n$ are a finite list of generators of $B$ as an $A$-algebra, then $b_1/1,\cdots,b_n/1$ are a finite list of generators of $B_a$ as an $A_a$-algebra: the morphism $A[t_1,\cdots,t_n]\to B$ by $t_i\mapsto b_i$ being surjective implies that the morphism $A_a[t_1,\cdots,t_n]\to B_a$ by $t_i/1\mapsto b_i/1$ is also surjective, since localization is exact.

Hi KReiser, thanks! I did not realize that fact.
